# Customizing Pmd

Tags: plugins, pmd

I want to create a rule in eclipse Pmd, not to check or scan classes which are existing ones and unmodified. The scan should only verify classes which have been modified or if a new class has been added in case. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Sonar.  Sonar can integrate with your SCM (git, subversion, etc) to determine which files have changed and then run your PMD rules against only those files/methods/lines.

PMD can't do what you want by itself.